# Svelte with Tailwind siding side panel: How do I set this up to use transitions?

Tags: tailwind-css, svelte

Either svelte or tailwind transitions.

This is basically copied from the tailwind components page with some changes to make it work as best as I knew how with svelte. The tailwind component page says it requires JS, but I cannot find any examples of the kind of JS that would be expected in order for it to work the way it does on the component page.

There's a comment block of tailwind classes, but I cannot find docs on how they are to be used.

The side panel works, as in it hides and shows and all the clicks are appropriate, but it snaps. I'd like it to slide in from the side.

How do I make it do a sliding anim/transition?

```
<aside
    class="relative z-10 "
    aria-labelledby="slide-over-title"
    role="dialog"
    aria-modal="true"
    class:block={showSidePanel}     << my toggle variable in Svelte
    class:hidden={!showSidePanel}
    on:click|stopPropagation|preventDefault={toggleSidePanel}
    transition:fly={{ x: 200, duration: 300 }}
>
    <!--
        Background backdrop, show/hide based on slide-over state.
    
        Entering: "ease-in-out duration-500"
          From: "opacity-0"
          To: "opacity-100"
        Leaving: "ease-in-out duration-500"
          From: "opacity-100"
          To: "opacity-0"
      -->
    <div
        class="fixed inset-0 bg-gray-500 bg-opacity-75 transition-opacity"
        class:block={showSidePanel}
        class:hidden={!showSidePanel}
    />

    <div class="fixed inset-0 overflow-hidden">
        <div class="absolute inset-0 overflow-hidden">
            <div class="absolute inset-y-0 right-0 mt-20 flex max-w-full pl-10">
                <!--
              Slide-over panel, show/hide based on slide-over state.
    
              Entering: "transform transition ease-in-out duration-500 sm:duration-700"
                From: "translate-x-full"
                To: "translate-x-0"
              Leaving: "transform transition ease-in-out duration-500 sm:duration-700"
                From: "translate-x-0"
                To: "translate-x-full"
            -->
                <div
                    class="my-auto h-full w-screen max-w-2xl"
                    on:click|stopPropagation|preventDefault={() => {
                        // this blocks clicks closing the sidepanel
                    }}
                >
                    <div
                        class="m-auto flex h-[95%] flex-col overflow-y-scroll bg-white py-6 shadow-xl"
                    >
                        <div class="px-4 sm:px-6">
                            <div class="flex items-start justify-between">
                                <h2
                                    class="text-lg font-medium text-gray-900"
                                    id="slide-over-title"
                                >
                                    Panel title
                                </h2>
                                <div class="ml-3 flex h-7 items-center">
                                    <button
                                        type="button"
                                        class="rounded-md bg-white font-bold text-gray-400 hover:text-gray-500"
                                        on:click|stopPropagation={toggleSidePanel}
                                    >
                                        <span class="sr-only">Close panel</span>
                                        <Icon src={X} theme="solid" class="h-8 w-8 font-bold" />
                                    </button>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="relative mt-6 flex-1 px-4 sm:px-6">
                            <!-- Replace with your content -->
                            <div class="absolute inset-0 px-4 sm:px-6">
                                <div
                                    class="h-full border-2 border-dashed border-gray-200"
                                    aria-hidden="true"
                                />
                            </div>
                            <!-- /End replace -->
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</aside>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using classes to hide or show your sidebar you should use an {#if} block wrapped around the entire aside element to hide and show the sidebar and overlay.

Then you can use the Svelte transition that is right for each element. In the Tailwind comments it's using `translate-x-full` for the panel transition to get a similar effect you can bind the `clientWidth` of the actual panel to a variable and use that as the x amount in your Svelte fly transition.

Something like this (I removed some of your code since you had no components linked and used Tailwind CDN so the Tailwind classes would work like in [this REPL](https://svelte.dev/repl/d74f57d261bd454fb3bdec224f45f8c0?version=3.53.1)):

```
<script>
    import { fly, fade } from 'svelte/transition'
    let showSidePanel, width
    function toggleSidePanel() {
        showSidePanel = !showSidePanel
    }
</script>
<svelte:head>
<script src="https://cdn.tailwindcss.com"></script>
</svelte:head>
<div>
    <button class="p-3" on:click={toggleSidePanel}>
        Show side panel
    </button>
</div>
{#if showSidePanel}
<aside class="relative z-10">
    <div class="fixed inset-0 bg-gray-500 bg-opacity-75 transition-opacity" transition:fade/>
    <div class="fixed inset-0 overflow-hidden">
        <div class="absolute inset-0 overflow-hidden">
            <div class="absolute inset-y-0 right-0 mt-20 flex max-w-full pl-10">
                <div class="my-auto h-full w-screen max-w-2xl">
                    <div bind:clientWidth={width} transition:fly={{ x: width }} class="m-auto flex h-[95%] flex-col overflow-y-scroll bg-white py-6 shadow-xl">
                        <div class="px-4 sm:px-6">
                            <div class="flex items-start justify-between">
                                <h2 class="text-lg font-medium text-gray-900">
                                    Panel title
                                </h2>
                                <div class="ml-3 flex h-7 items-center">
                                    <button class="rounded-md bg-white font-bold text-gray-400 hover:text-gray-500" on:click={toggleSidePanel}>
                                        close
                                    </button>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="relative mt-6 flex-1 px-4 sm:px-6">
                            <div class="absolute inset-0 px-4 sm:px-6">
                                <div class="h-full border-2 border-dashed border-gray-200" aria-hidden="true">Some content</div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</aside>
{/if}
```

Comment: This is really nice. Thank you. I had forgotten that `{#if}` is the best condition for svelte transitions. I looked up `clientWidth` which was my biggest question. I had probably forgotten that the split second I left the tutorial page. A thing to know and remember.

Comment: Lol never a bad idea to revisit the tutorial, glad to hear it all worked out for you.